# How to get SVN revision in Gradle for Android?

Tags: android, svn, gradle, revision, gradle-eclipse

I have field (svn revision) in resource. How can I get svn revision in my field using by Gradle, that not to do that by my hands?

Comment: isn't my answer helped?

Answer (score 5):

You could modify the following solution, [explained here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/gradle-goodness-parse-output-from-exec.html), which prints out the current SVN revision.

```
// File: build.gradle
task svninfo << {
    new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
        def result = exec {
            executable = 'svn'
            args = ['info']
            standardOutput = os
        }
        def outputAsString = os.toString()
        def matchLastChangedRev = outputAsString =~ /Last Changed Rev: (\d+)/
        println "Latest Changed Revision #: ${matchLastChangedRev[0][1]}"
    }
}

// Example output for svn info:
// Path: .
// URL: http://svn.host/svn/project
// Repository Root: http://svn.host/svn/
// Repository UUID: 9de3ae54-a9c2-4644-a1a1-838cb992bc8e
// Revision: 33
// Node Kind: directory
// Schedule: normal
// Last Changed Author: mrhaki
// Last Changed Rev: 33
// Last Changed Date: 2010-09-03 14:25:41 +0200 (Fri, 03 Sep 2010)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
task svnversion {
  description 'Get SVN revision number.'
  new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
    def result = exec {
      executable = 'svnversion'
      standardOutput = os
    }
    ext.revid = os.toString()
  }
}
```

You can test it with

```
task printsvn(description: 'Demonstrate calling svnversion task.') {
  println 'Implementation-Build #' + svnversion.revid
}
```

The results

$ gradle printsvn
:printsvn
Implementation-Build #3071

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.776 secs