# Add the build SVN revision number in Android Studio

Tags: android, svn, android-studio, version-control

I would like to use the Subversion revision number as an additional specifier of the Version of my App. I am working with Android Studio, therefore I am using Gradle.
I did not find a friendly way to access the Subversion revision and then read it from code.

It would be fantastic if the SVN revision number could be added to `BuildConfig` class generated by Gradle.

Answer (score 2):

I made it work using mostly code from this comment: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25872141/5132130

I added the following to the top of the gradle file:

```
def getSvnRevisionNr() {
    description 'Get SVN revision number.'
    new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
        def result = exec {
            executable = 'svnversion'
            standardOutput = os
        }
        return '"' + os.toString().trim() + '"'
    }
}
```

The changes I made in relation to the comment I linked:

- I wanted a result that could be used for the String, so I needed to add the '"' parts and the trim()
- I returned it as is, without storing in variable inside method

And in my buildTypes:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        buildConfigField("String", "SVN_REVISION", getSvnRevisionNr())
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        buildConfigField("String", "SVN_REVISION", getSvnRevisionNr())

    }
}
```

Then in my code i can access it using:

```
BuildConfig.SVN_REVISION
```